# How to map functions twice?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, map, index

I would like to plot multiple lists. The table looks like

```
a={{1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0},{1,2,3,0,0,0,2,0,0},...,{1,2,3,0,0,0,0,3,0}}
```

I want to plot the elements from 4 to end with index*step as x-axis. For the first line

```
ListPlot[{# step,a[[1,#]]}& /@ Range[4, Length[a[[1]]]
```

If I would like to plot all the rows in the same plot, looks I have to change the a[[1,#]] to a[[#2,#]] and map again with Range[Length[a]]

How could I do that?

Comment: I assume your list of data is `a`.  I think you're trying to do `ListPlot[a[All,4;;]]`?

Comment: ... or `ListPlot[Drop[a, None, 3]]`.

Comment: Thanks above two comments. Actually, I have to change the question a little bit, the x-axis is not index. It is index times a constant. That is why I use map here. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `DataRange -> step {4, Length[a[[1]]]}` to evanb's comment

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the evanb's comment above and just add the option for [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html):

```
ListPlot[a[[;;, 4 ;;]], DataRange -> step {4, Length[First@a]}]
```

This will plot your data without an explicit `x` coordinate, but you specify the x-axis range with `DataRange`.
If you really need to generate a list of pairs of coordinates, you can do this:

```
ListPlot[Thread[{step Range[4, Length[First@a]], #[[4 ;;]]}] & /@ a]
```

For `step=20`:

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using combination of MapThread and Map.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 
3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

Assuming step is say 0.1, we will generate list of x-co-ordinates

```
    step = 0.1;
xlist = step*Range[4, Length[a[[1]]]];
```

Now using MapThread and Map, we can generate pairs.

```
pairs = Flatten[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {xlist, #[[4 ;;]]}] & /@ a, 1]
```

This will generate output

```
{{0.4, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 0}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 0}, {0.4, 
  0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 1}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 0}, {0.4, 
  0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 2}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 0}, {0.4, 
  0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.6, 0}, {0.7, 0}, {0.8, 0}, {0.9, 1}}
```

which you can use as input to ListPlot

```
ListPlot[pairs, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large]]]
```

Hope this is helpful. 
One advantage of MapThread is it could be easily generalized to include more lists (say if you want to plot points in 3D).